# How can I add arrayList to alert dialog and select one of them?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have week days with `arrayListOf` `string` *(tarihArrForAlim)* and I need to manipulate them. I need to show this arraylist on alert dialog and select one of them. In this point I can show them when I add `setMessage` but I can't select obviously. I need to show `arrayListOf<String>()` to alert dialog but I can't find any way to do it. How can I show and select this list in alert dialog?

**Array which is talked about :**

```
    var tarihArrForAlim = arrayListOf<String>()
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
    for (i in 1..8) {
        val calendar: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, i)
        val day = sdf.format(calendar.time)
        println(day + "bugun gunlerden..")
        tarihArrForAlim.add(day)
    }
```

**And here my alert dialog:**

```
    val AlimTarihiSecmeButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.alim_tarihi_button)
    AlimTarihiSecmeButton.setOnClickListener {



        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@SiparisOnayi)
        mBuilder.setTitle("Alım için tarih seçiniz")

        //mBuilder.setMessage(tarihArrForAlim.toString())


        mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(tarihArrForAlim, -1) { dialogInterface, i ->
          
            alim_tarihi_button.text = tarihArrForAlim[i].toString()  
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
        }


        mBuilder.setNeutralButton("İptal") { dialog, which ->
            
            dialog.cancel()
        }
        val mDialog = mBuilder.create()
        mDialog.show()

    }
```

Comment: You should put a spinner view in the alert dialog and populate the spinner with the elements of your arraylist

Comment: I want to use only alert dialog without spinner view because I think it is more suitable for my application. Is there any way to do it without spinner view? If not I need to do it.

Comment: in order to select something you need a view, it could be a spinner view or a recyclerview but you need a dedicated view to select a particular item, you can't select an array from the user interface